# finding the strike / maturity of warrants given their ISINs

Tags: options, equities, bloomberg

I have a list of French traded warrants identified by their ISINs. I do not know, however, to which stock they refer and what is their strike/maturity.

Which datasets allow me to retrieve this information?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the Bloomberg tag so I will assume that you have access to a Bloomberg terminal.

Let's say your ISIN is `FR0011671296`.

- In the terminal, you can type: `ID <Go>` then type the ISIN and the security's page will open. You can then type `DES <Go>` to see the details.
- If you are in Excel, you can use the API. For example to get the underlying you would use: `=BDP("FR0011671296 ISIN", "OPT UNDL TICKER")`. To find other fields, the best way is to go back to the terminal and type, for example, `FLDS MATURITY <Go>` and you will see a list of related fields that you can use in Excel.

Comment: thank you very much for this helpful comment. Do you know if that information would be also available in Optionmetrics? Are options and warrants priced similarly?

Comment: I don't know optionmetrics.